# Экземпляры WCF службы и переменные

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Служба работает в режиме по умолчанию т.е perSession, что означает, что на каждое подключение создается по экземпляру.
Не могу понять, почему в одном и том же контексте при повторном обращении к службе я теряю сохраненные переменные в экземпляре...
Подскажите, что я упускаю ?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в basicHttpBinding. Сменил на wsHttpBinding и все заработало

Comment: Извиняюсь за прошлый комментарий - перепутал с другим биндингом.